# How can I pass a selected value from select into a link in the same view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

i have an select dropdown like that in my view:

```
<select name="table" class="form-control" id="db_table">
@foreach($tables as $table)
<option value="{{$table->id}}">{{$table->name}}</option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

And I want to pass the id which is in option value of the select to a link used in the same view. I can't use post form, because i want to use the value in another route.

Comment: I'm not quite clear what you're asking for here. Are you looking to dynamically change the url of a link in the same page based on which option the user selects?

Comment: Something like that. I want to get currently selected option value and pass it like that: <a href="/{{$<value>}}">

Comment: It's important to know if you need to do it only on page load (once) or do you need it to be dynamic as the user changes it.

Comment: I guess it has to be dynamically

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get selected value in dropdown list using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1085801/get-selected-value-in-dropdown-list-using-javascript)

Comment: but can i get javascript variable using blade synthax?

Comment: Blade is just a templating engine and has nothing to do with how javascript is written. Create your script and include it in your template as you would normally include it in an ordinary html page.

Comment: ok so, to be clear, can I write var variable=document.getElementById('elementId').value and use it like {{$variable}}

Comment: No, because js is client side. But when you're first loading your page, you don't need javascript to determine it, you know in your blade file which option will be selected by default.

Comment: I'm lost. Assuming that i wrote a javascript function that sets the variable to be the value of select and set it to onchanged in select, what do I have to write inside <a href=""> to have that variable in the url? (edit: the url willbe more like "something/<value>"

Comment: Your default selected value. When you render a `<select>`, an option is selected by default (if you don't specify yourself, then it's the first one). This is just the *initial* value on page load. You only later change it with javascript.

Comment: The function look like this: function getSelectedValue()
        {
            var v=document.getElementById('db_table').value;
        }. I don't think it changes the default selected option

Comment: It doesn't change anything, it just fetches. Just use the id of the first option in blade `{{$tables[0]->id}}`.

Comment: I tried it, now its always '1' in the url no matter which option i select

Comment: Then most likely your javascript is not doing its job. Consult the linked question from my earlier comment.

Comment: Do I have to write addEventListener inside script for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly you want to dynamically change the URL with the selected value from dropdown.

Use `onchange` event listener using JavaScript or JQuery which will allow you to get the selected value from select and then you can do whatever you want with that value.

Using JQuery

```
$("selecterIdOrClass").change(function(){
  $("selecterIdOrClass").attr('href',$(this).val());
});
```